# How to limit service availability based on CPU usage?

Tags: kubernetes

My Pods are allocated 1000m CPU. I would like to make Pod not-Ready when CPU usage is over 900m or 90% of the allocated resources.

Is there a configuration for this or do I need to implement a check in my application that would signal readiness based on the CPU usage?

Comment: [`readinessProbe:` accepts a bunch of options](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.25/#probe-v1-core) including (as sounds like your case) `exec:`; what have you already tried and what's it doing for you instead of un-Readying your Pod?

Comment: The question is whether there is a canonical way of doing it. I've written a few libraries that do this, like [Lightship](https://github.com/gajus/lightship). But implementing this in user land is error prone.

Comment: The reason I want to make the pod not-Ready when CPU is over 90% is because high congestion is causing the service to stop responding snappy. I would rather it become unavailable and use that signal to spin up more replicas.

Comment: There's for sure no canonical way, but I mentioned `exec` because I would expect if the pod is able to determine its own cpu usage (akin to `top` although certainly not _via_ `top`), or it was able to ask metrics-server about itself, then returning bogus from the pod's `exec` would de-Ready it